# and ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3

I have installed TensorFlow with Anaconda but it shows an error.

I have the following versions:

```
Python                    3.9.13
keras                     2.11.0
tensorflow                2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator      2.11.0
tensorflow-gpu            2.10.1
tensorboard               2.11.0
```

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-gpu 2.10.1 requires keras<2.11,>=2.10.0, but you have keras 2.11.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-gpu 2.10.1 requires tensorboard<2.11,>=2.10, but you have tensorboard 2.11.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-gpu 2.10.1 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.11,>=2.10.0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.11.0 which is incompatible.
```

Additionally, I get this error when I run

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization
```

This is the error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6684\2805265792.py in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

I have tried the following:

```
pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow
```

```
pip install keras==2.11
```

```
pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.11
```

```
pip install tensorboard==2.11
```

But nothing works.

Comment: How, exactly, are you running the code?  Are you typing `python myscript.py` at a command like, or are you using an IDE, or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first error, I think you just need to install the compatible versions:

```
pip install keras==2.10.0 tensorboard==2.10 tensorflow-estimator==2.10.0
```

Regarding the second error, have you tried to do:

```
from keras.layers import TextVectorization
```

instead of using `tensorflow.keras`?

(Of course you have to install keras with `pip install keras` first)

Comment: I tried 'pip install keras==2.10.0 tensorboard==2.10 tensorflow-estimator==2.10.0
'
Still shows this error
'ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed.
tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 requires keras<2.12,>=2.11.0, but you have keras 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 requires tensorboard<2.12,>=2.11, but you have tensorboard 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow-intel 2.11.0 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.12,>=2.11.0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.10.0 which is incompatible.'

Comment: Since you have all tensorflow-related packages at version 2.11 but tensorflow-gpu at  version 2.10, maybe try to install tensorflow-gpu 2.11 and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Tried to install 'pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.11.0' but receiving  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==2.11.0 ...

Comment: could you send the versions on your end.
 For tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Unfortunately, I work with an m1 chip so the installation process is different.
Other than trying different combinations of package versions I don't know how to solve the problem. 
You can try to install the packages with --no-deps to ignore the dependency-related problems and see if it works, but in that case the package could not work at all.

Comment: Well go it to work,
All it took was to remove all tensorflow files from the Anaconda3 'pip list' and using 'pip uninstall 'file_name''

Answer (score 0):

Well I it got it to work,

All it took was to remove all `tensorflow` files and `keras` from the Anaconda3

1. `pip list'
2. Then using 'pip uninstall 'file_name''
3. Then reinstalling tensorflow, `pip install tensorflow tensorflow-gpu`

And the second error fixed itself after the reinstallation.